# Error on require 'motion-cocoapods' with RubyMotion

Tags: ruby, rubymotion, cocoapods

I just got Ruby motion, and I wanted to try out Cocoapods. I installed it just as it asks on the website:

http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/cocoapods/

I add

require 'motion-cocoapods' to my simple 'Hello' project. And I get this error when trying to rake it:

rake aborted!
Unable to activate cocoapods-0.16.1, because rake-10.0.3 conflicts with rake (~> 0.9.4)

I guess this has something to do with my version of rake, but I have no idea what I need to do to fix this problem. Please help!

Comment: Maybe `gem update rake`?

Comment: I wish it was that simple but no! Says nothing to update

Comment: when I do a gem list, it does appear I have two versions of rake for some reason now -> rake (10.0.3, 0.9.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by having a version of rake newer than 0.9.x installed. When you just run `rake`, it loads up the newest version (10.0.3 in your case). Then, when the cocoapod gem tries to load, it tries to activate rake 0.9.x and fails (the `~> 0.9.4` means that it will accept any version starting with `0.9.`).

One solution would be to completely remove the `rake` gem and install the 0.9.4 version explicitly:

```
gem uninstall rake
gem install rake --version '0.9.6'
```

However, this could become an issue if you have any other projects that require a newer version of rake. A better solution would be to use Bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

Create a `Gemfile` in your project folder containing:

```
source :rubygems
gem 'rake'
gem 'motion-cocoapods'
```

Add the following to `Rakefile`, immediately under the `require 'motion/project'` line:

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require
```

Then run `bundle install` from the console. This will lock this specific project on rake 0.9.6. The only catch is that you'll probably need to prefix all of your rake commands with `bundle exec`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by following the steps on this japanese blog:

http://blog.amacou.net/post/37702092871/rubymotion-cocoapods-rake

First uninstall:

gem uninstall motion-cocoapods
gem uninstall cocoapods

download cocoapods :

git clone git://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods.git

find the gemspec file

and change this:

s.add_runtime_dependency 'rake',          '~> 0.9.4'

to this:

s.add_runtime_dependency 'rake',          '> 0.9.4'

then install it as a gem

rake gem:install

then reinstall motion-cocoapods:

gem install motion-cocoapods

My feeling is this is a hack though, and I'm worried it could cause problems else where. If anyone has a better answer, please post it.